# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shapefile'

Tags: python

I tried to import the shapefile into anaconda spyder, but there are problems
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shapefile'

Am I missing something here, and should I try all the matches from PyPi search without any reason? I'm a little lost here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you run import shapefile, you must to do install pyshp using:

> conda install -c conda-forge pyshp

In your command prompt and wait until the installation process is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run `pip install pyshp` from your command line.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any module called shapefile. You need to install pyshp module with the command:

```
pip install PyShp
```

If you want to know more about, you can read about here: https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).